# Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation

Tags: spring-boot

> I have problem in build this project, I can not properly configure the dataSource bean.I recently updated the Config class.May be instanciation of Datasource creating the problem.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver



server.port = 8081
```

Bean definition

```
@Bean

public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

But get following Exception,that i can not resolve.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to provide this configuration:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

Spring already uses the configurations starting with `spring` to create the instance of the `DataSource`. Please refer [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) of the documentation.

**EDIT**
That makes no difference. You can inject `DataSource` instance in the class that configures clients. If you want to initialize the tables, you can create two files: `data-<dbName>.sql` and `schema-<dbName>.sql` and place them in the resources directory. The last thing you could do, if you still want to use this setup, is to rename the variables in `application.properties` to not use `Spring's` property keys. Please use [this reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-database-initialization) for initializing databases.

The problem that you are facing could be very well related to these two methods as well:

@Bean

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
}


@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}
```

What is happening is, I guess, that you have a member variable of the class called `dataSource` that you are initializing somehow (probably via `@Autowired`) which is being used in `dataSourceInitializer` method. Now, when this bean is being created, it requires that there is an instance of `dataSource` but that object is not available as the containing class is still being initialized. Could you please have a look into this. Probably post the whole class.

**EDIT 2:**
As expected, the error is due to the fact that you are trying to inject `DataSource` when it is still being created. The simplest solution is to remove this line:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Once you have done that, change the implementation of `dataSourceInitializer` to use the `dataSource()` as:

```
initializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
```

This should fix the issue circular dependency

Comment: dataSource bean is needed for clients.jdbc(dataSource()).

Comment: if i use jdbc.driverClassName;jdbc,url; will it work?

Comment: Please post the complete class so that the exact cause could be analysed!

Comment: You do not need to post exact code if it is a propriety one. You can however recreate the problem with minimum code. Like I said, the thing to check here is if you are injecting `DataSource` in the same class as you are using it.

Comment: I updated the class where i autowired the dataSource.

Comment: Thanks for your help,however i can not remove @Autowired DataSource dataSource bcoz it is in another class and i need to use that dataSource object in that class.But i have used initializer.setDataSource(dataSource()) in the datasourceInitializer method, but it is as same as before.

Comment: Nice! completely forgot the `@Lazy` annotation. :D

Comment: But @Lazy doesnot work in springboot 1.5.9.RELEASE version may be.